# How to get more detailed constraint failure assertions from SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I've built a tool for some analysts that involves `.import`ing a bunch of analyst generated csv files into a SQLite database as the first step. The csv files correspond to tables and there are many foreign key constraints and other integrity checks in the schema.

The users will be reasonably smart and technical people, but they will not necessarily know anything about relational databases, and the error messages SQlite produces by default are not clear enough on their own. Ideally the resolution to the problem should be clear from the constraint failure message.

Example:

```
scheduled_duration.csv:9: INSERT failed: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

I would like to produce a message more like:

```
scheduled_duration.csv:9: Referenced column training_track ('9345') does not exist.
```

The schema already knows this additional information about the failing constraint. Is there an easy way I'm overlooking to get such an improved message? Having to eventually manually implement my own integrity checks on the data just to get better error messages would be a huge pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [deferred foreign key constraints](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_deferred), SQLite must be able to remember an arbitrary number of FK constraint violations. To make the implementation easier, this is implemented with an error counter, and it's used even if no FK constraints are actually deferred.

So with the current implementation, it is not possible to get a better error message.